# Move button to center

Tags: html, css, button, width, contact-form-7

I was wondering if someone knows how can I move this button slightly to the left so it goes straight to the center. This is the code:

```
      <!-- Modal for Contact - us Button -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Contáctanos</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form action="https://formsubmit.co/myemail.com" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="Name">Nombre</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" placeholder="Nombre" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="Phone">Celular</label>
                  <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Celular" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="Email">Correo</label>
                  <input type="Email" class="form-control" id="Email-1" placeholder="Correo" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="Message">Mensaje</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" id="Message" placeholder="Ingresa tu mensaje" required></textarea>
                </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin:0;display:block;width:100%">Enviar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

here a picture of what I'm trying to say: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjXAo.jpg Hope someone can help me out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell what you need to do without seeing the css, but I think that if you adjust the padding-left on the modal-footer class you should be able to move the button to the right. If you could upload what your css classes look like, that would be very helpful.

Comment: style.css is huge: https://codeshare.io/Lw8vKK

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the button CSS:

```
.btn-success { margin: 0 auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply below css:

```
 text-align: center;  
 margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin:0;display:block;width:100%">Enviar</button>
</div>

Just Use this one line style

<div class="modal-footer" style="justify-content: space-around;">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Enviar</button>
</div>
```